# How do I increase size of text in an image input type field?

Tags: html, css, input

I have an input field as:

```
<input type="image" name="submit" value="submit" src="images/searchb1.png" id="button1"/>
```

Now I want to increase the size of the text `Submit` on that field. How can I achieve that using css?

Comment: Your question is not clear to us, Add images, code or any link.

Answer (score 1):

with css:

```
input{font-size: SIZE;}
```

Answer (score 1):

**NEW CODE**

Made Changes, because you needed to increase the submit button font size

```
input
{
    font-size:40px;
}
```

or

```css
input[type='submit']
{
    font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**OLD CODE**
Try This code

```
input[type='text']
{
    font-size:30px;
}
```

or

```css
input
{
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here">
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS, if you make your HTML input more specific we can be more specific. As of now, here is a general way of doing it.

```
input{font-size: 50px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
input type="button" id="SubmitButton" value="Submit" />
```

Css:

```
input#SubmitButton{
font-size: 10em;
}
```

Check out [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_submit.asp) information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your html

```
 <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

CSS

```
input{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want to use inline css.

```
    <input type="button" value="Submit" style="font-size:20px;"></input>
```

Alternatively page/external css;

```
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Submit"></input>
```

CSS

```
    input{
           font-size:20px;
    }
```

I also created a jsfiddle that you can edit easily to your liking.
https://jsfiddle.net/t048Lk5z/